Reading Kafka data with zstd compression using scala spark
We are trying to read data from Kafka Producer, with zstd compression.
But getting error -
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/github/luben/zstd/ZstdOutputStreamNoFinalizer

We are using Spark 3.3.2 and scala 12.2.14.
Tried adding -

Jar file - zstd-jni-1.5.2-3.jar
Dependency in pom.xml -

<dependency>
     <artifactId>zstd-jni</artifactId>
     <groupId>com.github.luben</groupId>
     <version>1.5.2-1</version> 
</dependency>

but still same error. Any idea how to resolve this issue?

NoClassDefFoundError is caused by some piece of code is trying to access that class and can't be found because it's not in the classpath. My guess is that there is some conflict in the version of the lib. Of course the root cause could be something else. Could you share the pom you have?

How are you packaging/deploying the app? Especially: is the JAR actually deployed where Spark expects it? Another possibility is a version conflict (Spark comes with a lot of libs on its own).

According to https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.3.2/pom.xml#L788, Spark 3.3.2 already has zstd-jni-1.5.2-1 as a dependency, so technically you dont need it in your .pom, or should use a  scope if your code itself references zstd codec.

In the text it says 1.5.2-3 in pom.xml it says 1.5.2-1
Did you try something along the lines of
spark-submit [....] --jars path/to/zstd-jni-1.5.2-3.jar
Also the zstd-jni version is somewhere around ~2 years old and the Spark version is around 18 months old. Did you check if they are compatible?
